# Convergence of binomial distribution of with random parameter.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y \in [0,1]$ be a random variable. Conditioning $Y$, $X_n$ has binomial distribution with parameters $(n, P)$. By law of large number, we have, conditioning on $Y$,
$$
\frac {X_n}{n} \to P,
$$
almost surely.
But if we do not condition on $P$, do we still have
$$
\frac {X_n}{n} \to P,
$$
almost surely?

I think this is true if $Y$ is discrete, but if $Y$ is continuous, this is probably not the case in general.

And do we still have
$$
\frac {X_n}{n} \to P,
$$
in probability being true in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y \sim U(0,1)$, and $X_i|Y=y \sim Ber(y)$, for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$, thus given $Y=y$
$$
n^{1/2}\frac{ (\bar{X}_n - y) }{\sqrt{y(1-y)}} \xrightarrow{D}N(0,1),
$$
as such, for large enough (and constant) $n$ the approximate distribution of the sample mean given $Y=y$ is $N(y, y(1-y)/n)$. In particular, 
$$
E\bar{X}_n= E[E[\bar{X}_n|Y]]= E[Y]=1/2,
$$
and
$$
Var(\bar{X}_n)=E (Var(\bar{X}_n|Y)) + Var(E(\bar{X}_n|Y))=\frac{1}{n}(EY - EY^2)+1/12 \to 1/12.
$$
However, 
$$
f_{X|Y=y}(x|y)= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)},
$$
thus
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1\cdot N(0,1) = N(0,1) .
$$
So I would guess that $\bar{X}_n$ does not converge in probability to $U(0,1)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = N(0,1)$? One side is a density function, the other is a random variable.

Comment: $N(0,1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\{-z^2/2\}$